# How to replace two double quotes with a single double quote in Java String?

Tags: java

I am reading a CSV file and have some values like

```
field 1   field 2           field 3
1        test case1         expecting one, and \"two\", and three
```

after reading file into a `StringBuilder` and converting `toString()` I split the file content by: `string.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");`.

On iterating the string I get these values:-

```
1
test case1
expecting one, and ""two"", and three
```

How I can I replace two double quotes with single double like this "two"

here is my code:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class csvStringParser {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          String path = "E:/spc.csv";

            String read = readFile(path);
            System.out.println("content of the file before \" = \n"  +read);



//      System.out.println("content of the file after= \n"  +read);

        String[] tokens = read.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
            for(int i = 0;i<tokens.length;i++) {
                String abc = tokens[i].replace("\"\"", "\"");

           //   if(abc.length()>2){
                if(abc.startsWith("\"") && abc.endsWith("\"")){ 
                abc = abc.substring(1, abc.length()-1);
                }
            //  } 

                System.out.println("> "+abc);
            }

    }

    public static String readFile( String file ) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (file));
        String         line = null;
        StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append( line );
            stringBuilder.append( ls );
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
String input = "this string \"\"has\"\" double quotes";
String output = input.replace("\"\"", "\"");
```

http://ideone.com/xPQqL

Comment: Doesn't works for me if I write String read = readFile(path);     read.replace("\"\"","\"");

Comment: I do see it now. No, I don't see anything glaringly obvious. Could you put together an ideone example?

Comment: My code reads a csv file, which I cant provide at ideone. But if you create a csv file (comma delimiter) and put the three field values in a row, it reads the content fine but the two double quotes exists

Comment: @Matt Ball I got the problem, there was a different set of char sequence given by csv after read...I had to convert \\\"\" to \". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] tokens = read.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
for(int i = 0;i<tokens.length;i++)
    tokens[i]=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv(tokens[i]);
```